# How to initialize a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to add a lazy-initialization function to my class. I'm not very proficient with C++. Can someone please tell me how I achieve it.

My class has a private member defined as:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal;
```

Here's the original constructor that takes one parameter:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string file) :
animal(new Animal(file))
{}
```

I just added a parameter-less constructor and an Init() function. Here's the Init function I just added:

```
void MyClass::Init(string file)
{
    this->animal = ???;
}
```

What do I need to write there to make it equivalent to what constructor is doing?

Comment: Use [`std::make_unique<Animal>(file)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) in the member initializer list.

Comment: Simple example : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: For `???` you can use `std::make_unique<Animal>(file)`.

Comment: @dotNet C++ is a complex language with many layers, good and bad parts. If you are not very proficient with C++, you could take a look at https://isocpp.org/tour. It is a C++ introduction with modern C++. If you want to skip the introduction, get copies of the Effective C++ series.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
public :
    int a;
    A(int a)
    {
        this->a=a;

    }
};
class B
{
public :
    std::unique_ptr<A> animal;
    void Init(int a)
    {
        this->animal=std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(a));
    }
    void show()
    {
        std::cout<<animal->a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B *b=new B();
    b->Init(10);
    b->show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the same as doing `make_unique` as suggested by another friend?

Comment: Better is probably `this->animal = std::make_unique<A>(a);`

Comment: It's the same. Mine is just more lame, I think

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It tells me that I'm "attempting to reference a deleted function" when I write `animal = std::make_unique<Animal>(Animal(file));`.

Comment: @dotNET I said `std::make_unique<A>(a);` and you tried `std::make_unique<A>(A(a));`. Try my suggestion. ;)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: mmm...Being a C# guy, I'm probably missing something here, but both of these fail for me: 1. `Animal a(file); animal = std::make_unique<Animal>(a);` and 2. `animal = std::make_unique<Animal>(new Animal(file));`

Comment: So why not try what I suggested? Neither of those things are what I suggested. The first has `Animal a(file);`. Did I suggest that? (In my suggestion, the type name only appears in the angle brackets.) The second has `new Animal(file)`. Did I suggest that? (In my suggestion, there is no `new`.) Please try what I suggested and let me know if it works.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What is `a` in your syntax? Isn't it an object of `Animal` class? That is what I tried to create in both versions.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming you understand the answer you picked as the best answer. I don't see how you can understand this line, `this->animal=std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(a));`, and not understand what `a` is. It is the parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: OMG. All of a sudden It all became clear. Feeling so dumb. The confusion was caused by the fact that my parameter was named `file`, not `a`. Menos example was actually using `a`. Anyway, thanks for bearing with me. I have switched to this syntax now.

Comment: Yay! Glad it clicked. The `make_shared` function is pretty sweet. It constructs both the object and the "thunk" needed to track the object's reference count and destructor so that `shared_ptr`s work. It takes the same parameters as the object's constructors. In C++-11, it uses perfect forwarding. In prior versions, it takes them by value and `std::ref` or `std::cref` can be used to avoid copying where desired/needed.

Comment: delete b; is missing

Answer (score 13):

I think `animal.reset(new Animal(file))` is what you want.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset

Comment: Much shorter than other variants and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

class Amm{

    public:
    std::unique_ptr<double> myVar;
    explicit Amm(std::unique_ptr<double> ptr):myVar{ptr.release()}{}
};

int main(){
    Amm a(std::make_unique<double>(5));
    std::cout<<*a.myVar;

    return 0;

}
```