# android native executable erros in vector

Tags: android, c++, vector

i have a project im writing for native executable on android and im hoping for some help as im stuck.
in my current code i have this

```
const std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<String16>>> *users;
(*users).emplace_back(new String16("bob"));
```

it does compile however when ran it gives Segmentation fault

Comment: That's a ton of unique_ptrs. Why are you using all of those instead of simple `std::vector<String16>`? I can't think of any good reason for keeping a pointer to a vector or unique_ptrs inside of vector.

Comment: Segfault is raised because `users` stores `nullptr`, and the fix is easy - you have to allocate a vector using `std::make_unique<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<String16>>>()` or (pre C++14) `new std::vector<std::unique_ptr<String16>>`. But I really recommend rethinking your design to avoid these two pointer layers if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicates [Accessing struct member through unique_ptr gives segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934661/accessing-struct-member-through-unique-ptr-gives-segmentation-fault)(closed) or [How to initialize a unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624077/how-to-initialize-a-unique-ptr) or maybe just close as typo, not sure.

Comment: Dereferencing a `nullptr` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In addition, since here the `std::unique_ptr` is declared `const` for some reason, `std::make_unique<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<String16>>>()` must be given in the initializer of the declaration, not at a later assignment.

Comment: i am using const std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<String16>>> users; due to it is what is mapped to  List<String> in java

"Consider an AIDL type in @nullable List<String> bar. This type indicates that the remote caller may pass in a list of strings, and that both the list and any string in the list may be null. This type will map to a C++ type unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<String16>>>* bar. In this case:"

Comment: @LaurenceCardoza Java is *not* C++. In any case, you need to initialize your `unique_ptr` before you dereference it.

Comment: @LaurenceCardoza As reference for others: Your quote is from [this documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md).

Comment: @Jesper Juhlnot in anyway stating that java is c++ the vector is sent to an android itelephony (java) function which expects list<String>

Comment: @uneven_mark sorry for not sourcing where i got the info that was clearly wrong of me and yes that is correct thats why i use the way i did

Comment: @LaurenceCardoza You still need to recognize that even though these type mappings are made, the types don't have the same exact semantics in the languages. Before using this, look up what `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector` are and how they work. Then you can try to use them (or better translate them to some simpler type as soon as possible). For example `std::unique_ptr` needs to be initialized with a pointer to an object of the managed type, as explained above.

Comment: thank everyone for the help, still trying

Comment: I have tried to simplify the vector however the function it is sent doesnt except it nor am i able to set a value in vector to null unless i use vector as i have in op. I am new at c++ and clearly lack the skill and knowledge to accomplish this true greatful for those who gave response